# jquery selector with select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a page that for simplicity contains this:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="commonClass" data-attribute-one="some value" data-attribute-two="some value">
    .... (lots more rows)
</div>
```

At the top of the page I have two inputs for the user to search/filter results:

1. An html select to filter data-attribute-one to a single selection.
2. An input box to filter data-attribute-two contains name.

The next challenge is that I wanted to combine the two searches / filters, e.g. find all rows with an data-attribute-one value of "A" AND all rows with a data-attribute-two containing (*=) 'AAAA'.  I satisfied that with the following:

```
$(".commonClass[data-attribute-one='" + searchValue1 +"']"[data-attribute-two*='" + searchValue2 +"']")
```

What I'm having a hard time with is how to handle the case where the user nulls out a search field or selects "all" from the drop down (to filter data-attribute-one)?  Is there any way to change my existing selector to better handle an empty ('') searchValue1 and/or searchValue2?  Or, is the solution to dynamically construct the selector along the lines of, e.g.

```
selector = ".commonClass"
if ( searchValue1 != '' ) {
   selector += "[data-attribute-one='" + searchValue1 +"']"
} ... etc
```

Comment: Personally I'd go with your last option. That way when you're debugging, your `selector` will be simple and easy to read.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the example solution you've provided. I can't think of anything any more eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments from Joe Enos and Jaw.sh, I wrote a method to construct the selector:

```
function constructSearchSelector() {
    var selector = ".commonClasss";
    if ( searchValue1 != '' ) {
        selector += "[data-attribute-one='" + searchValue1 + "']";
    }
    if ( searchValue2 != '' ) {
        selector += "[data-attribute-two*='" + searchValue2 + "']";
    }
    return selector;
}
```

This way I can easily add on more search criteria and I can easily debug the constructed value.  Thanks for the comments!